# still fighting angular observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I thought I was finally beginning to understand this, but obviously I'm still missing something. I'm trying to create the observable using BehaviorSubject in my app settings service. I think I understand the steps to properly create the observable. But now when I have some new values to update the observable with, Angular craps out a runtime telling me next is undefined for my Behavior service.

Here is the updated code:

```
import { Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { AppSettings } from '../shared/app-settings';
import { APPSETTINGS } from "../shared/defaultSettings";
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { LOCAL_STORAGE, StorageService } from 'angular-webstorage-service';
import { LogService } from 'src/app/services/app-log.service';


@Injectable()
export class AppSettingsService {
  className: string;
  settings: AppSettings;

  @Input()
    // Use of BehavioirSubject. This is where you post values into
    private _settings$: BehaviorSubject<AppSettings> = new BehaviorSubject<AppSettings>(APPSETTINGS)
    // Settings observer. This is where you read from outside
    settings$: Observable<AppSettings> = this._settings$.asObservable();



    constructor(private logger: LogService,
                @Inject(LOCAL_STORAGE) private storage: StorageService) {
      this.className = this.constructor.toString().match(/\w+/g)[1];
      /*
       * First, we check to see if this is the first time the app has
       * been run on this machine. If it is, then local storage will return
       * null when we ask for the settings. We'll populate local storage
       * with the default settings values before we continue on setting up 
       * the service.
       */
       this.settings = this.storage.get('TRACS3_SETTINGS');
       if ( this.settings == null ) {
         try {
          this.storage.set('TRACS3_SETTINGS', APPSETTINGS);
         }
         catch(e) {
           console.log(this.className, 'Machine does not support local storage. ');
         }
       }

       /* 
          AppSettings are now initialized, set the initial value of them for all other
          components will use to monitor them.
        */
       console.log(this.className, 'about to set observable iniitial values');
       this.settings = this.storage.get('TRACS3_SETTINGS');
       this._settings$ = this.storage.get('TRACS3_SETTINGS');
       console.log(this.className, 'just changed observabe to ',     this._settings$);
}


    public saveSettings(settings: AppSettings): void{
      console.log(this.className, 'saving settings in service, new settings: ', settings);
      //this._settings$.post(settings)
      this.storage.set('TRACS3_SETTINGS', settings);
      this._settings$.next( settings );
    }


  //public getSettings(): AppSettings {
    //eturn this.storage.get('TRACS3_SETTINGS');
  //}

}
```

Now I'm getting different errors. If I try and set the Observer with this line of code:

```
this._settings$ = this.settings;
```

I get the error message:

```
Type 'AppSettings' is missing the following properties from type 'BehaviorSubject<AppSettings>': _value, value, _subscribe, getValue, and 19 more.ts(2740)
```

But when I put it to the value shown above (=this.storage.get...) I now get the runtime error

[image]

I'm at my wits end here. I don't what else to except maybe give up on angular altogether.

Comment: "@Input()" - input binding should not go into a service. Looking at the imports I recommend to update your project to the latest Angular version.

Comment: you missed the `BehavoirSubject` type when creating it. `private _settings$: BehaviorSubject<AppSettings> = new     BehaviorSubject<AppSettings>(APPSETTINGS)`

Comment: Added the AppSettings type and still get the same error. I did not understand the comment from Robert at all. Too cryptic for this feeble mind.

Comment: maybe this line overwrites it: this._settings$ = this.storage.get('TRACS3_SETTTINGS'); try to comment out or modify it to call "next(" method

Comment: @robert is correct, you're reassigning your `_settings$` `BehaviorSubject` in the `constructor()`

Comment: does anyone have any other ideas to try?

Comment: Did you try clearing npm_modules and running npm install to reinstall everything? Kind of grasping at straws but a fairly low hanging fruit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked one of the engineers (@JavRufus) at work about this (I haven't been coding in many years and am teaching myself the art once again). He came up with the following example for me.

appsettings.service.ts:

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
 import { AppSettings } from '../model/appsettings';

 @Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
 })

 export class AppSettingsService {

   private appSettings: AppSettings;
   private _appSettingsSubject: BehaviorSubject<AppSettings> = new BehaviorSubject(this.appSettings);

   constructor() {
     if (localStorage && localStorage.getItem('APP-SETTINGS') !== 'undefined') {
       this.appSettings = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('APP-SETTINGS'));
     } else {
       this.appSettings = new AppSettings();
       localStorage.setItem('APP-SETTINGS', JSON.stringify(this.appSettings));
     }
     this._appSettingsSubject.next(this.appSettings);
   }

   get behaviorSubject() {
     return this._appSettingsSubject;
   }

   set updateAppSettings(newAppSettings: AppSettings) {
     console.log('Service; update sessings:  ' + this.appSettings.userName + '; ' +      this.appSettings.password);
     this.appSettings = newAppSettings;
     if (localStorage) {
       localStorage.setItem('APP-SETTINGS', JSON.stringify(this.appSettings));
     }
     this._appSettingsSubject.next(this.appSettings);
   }

 }
```

sample-client.component.ts:

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 import { AppSettings } from '../model/appsettings';
 import { AppSettingsService } from '../config/appsettings.service';

 @Component({
   selector: 'app-sample-client',
   templateUrl: './sample-client.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./sample-client.component.css']
 })
 export class SampleClientComponent implements OnInit {

   appSettings: AppSettings;

   constructor(private appSettingsService: AppSettingsService) {}

   ngOnInit() {
     this.appSettings = this.appSettingsService.behaviorSubject.getValue();
   }

   updateAppSettings() {
     console.log('Client; update sessings:  ' + this.appSettings.userName + '; ' +      this.appSettings.password);
     this.appSettingsService.updateAppSettings = this.appSettings;
   }

 }
```

finally, followed by sample-receiver.component.ts:

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 import { AppSettings } from '../model/appsettings';
 import { AppSettingsService } from '../config/appsettings.service';
 import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

 @Component({
   selector: 'app-sample-receiver',
   templateUrl: './sample-receiver.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./sample-receiver.component.css']
 })
 export class SampleReceiverComponent implements OnInit {

   appSettings: AppSettings;

   appSettingsSub: Subscription;

   constructor(private appSettingsService: AppSettingsService) {}

   ngOnInit() {
     this.appSettings = this.appSettingsService.behaviorSubject.getValue();

     this.appSettingsSub =      this.appSettingsService.behaviorSubject.asObservable().subscribe(value => {
       this.appSettings = value;
     });
   }

 }
```

and of course the class appsettings.ts

```
 export class AppSettings {

   userName: string;
   password: string;

   constructor() {}

 }
```

Use this as your starting point and you should have no problem setting up a service to hold appSettings and then have a component to modify them and a component to receive notice of them changing.

Hopefully this will help someone else not spending 3 days looking for a solution like I did!

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor, you reassign `_settings$` with
`this._settings$ = this.storage.get('TRACS3_SETTINGS');`

The field is now whatever the value for `TRACS3_SETTING` is, and I guess that's not any kind of Observable.

You should use `this._settings$.next(this.storage.get('TRACS3_SETTINGS'));` to change its internal value